# Android 7 datagramsocket disconnect blocking

Tags: android, sockets, android-7.0-nougat

I have a 3rd party which uses the DatagramSocket for the device discovery, the problem is when performing a disconnect() while it's in the receive() mode, it blocks the thread.

I created a similar example, run it on Android 7 and compared with some lower version like Android 4.4.2, the result is the same: on Android 7 the disconnect blocks the thread while on the other version it works fine. Can anyone explain why it is happening? is there any solution for using disconnect and not blocking the thread?

```
DatagramSocket datagramSocket;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    int server_port = 12345;
    try {
        datagramSocket = new DatagramSocket(server_port);
    } catch (SocketException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }



    Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonDisconnect);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Log.d(TAG,"disconnect");
            datagramSocket.disconnect();
            Log.d(TAG,"close");
            datagramSocket.close();
            Log.d(TAG,"closed");

        }
    });

    Button button2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonStart);
    button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Thread t = new Thread() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    startDatagramSocket();
                }
            };
            t.start();
        }
    });

}

private void startDatagramSocket() {
    String text;
    Log.d(TAG,"startDatagramSocket");

    byte[] message = new byte[1500];
    DatagramPacket p = new DatagramPacket(message, message.length);
    try {
        datagramSocket.receive(p);
        text = new String(message, 0, p.getLength());
        Log.d(TAG,"message:" + text);
        datagramSocket.close();
    } catch (SocketException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Doing startDatagramSocket() and disconnecting leads to:

Android 7:

> 10-26 17:52:55.349 ...: disconnect

and ANR as I used the main thread

Android 4.4.2:

> 10-26 17:47:49.395 ...: disconnect
>
> 10-26 17:47:49.395 ...: close
>
> 10-26 17:47:49.395 ...: closed
>
> 10-26 17:47:49.395 ...: java.net.SocketException: Socket closed

The sample app is to make the point, I didn't add a connection to the DataSocket like on the 3rd party, but the behavior is reproducible.

Comment: calling `close()` instead of `disconnect()` won't block the caller thread, i think

Comment: close doesn't block it, but still, I am wondering if there is any solution being able to use disconnect